# Redirect loop when trying to publish a checkin via Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, checkin

I am trying to publish a checkin using facebook api. Sometimes, it works well and posts the checkin, but mostly 99% of the times it produces the error: "This webpage has a redirect loop"

**checkin.php:**

```
<?php
require("../src/facebook.php");

// construct the object with your facebook app data
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'XXXXX',
'secret' => 'XXXX',
'cookie' => false
));
    $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    //echo $token;exit())
try {
    // to get the id of the currently logged in user
    // if, you want you can manually set a user id here like this:
    //$uid = '[FB USER ID]';
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $facebook->setAccessToken($token);


        $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/checkins', 'POST', array(
        'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(),
        'place' => '101697613295949',
        'message' => 'Enjoying Chill Beer with Team',
        'picture' => 'http://test.com/someplace.png',
        'coordinates' => json_encode(array(
           'latitude'  => '28.541203543000023',
           'longitude' => '77.15503053709995',
           'tags' => 'XXXX'))
        ));
        echo 'You are checked in';

} catch (Exception $e){
    // No user found - ask the person to login
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    header("Location: ".$login_url);
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.